# cant seem to pass params to constructor

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I have a CustomWebViewClass:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomWebView extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //progress bar optional
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        final Activity activity = this;
        Toast.makeText(activity, "YO! " + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
                // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
                activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
            }
        });
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

from another class (a button essentially) I am trying to call this class as an intent passing it a URL like so:

```
Intent webView = new Intent(getContext(), CustomWebView.class);
webView.putExtra("url", "http://google.com");
webView.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getContext().startActivity(webView);
```

but I get a black screen or an error.. obviously I am doing something wrong, please help

oh and my manifest has this:

```
<activity android:name=".CustomWebView"
    android:label="CustomWebView"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.CUSTOMWEBVIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `params` on `Intent`, you can retrieve this with `getIntent().getExtra[...]`

try this :

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomWebView extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

         //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


         WebView webview = new WebView(this);
         setContentView(webview); 
        //progress bar optional
         getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        // alllow js
         webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

         final Activity activity = this;
         Toast.makeText(activity, "YO! " + url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
           public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
             // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
             activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
           }
         });
         webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
             Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
         });

         webview.loadUrl(url);



    }


}
```

Comment: thanks i tried that but something is still wrong as i get this error:03-27 10:50:30.240: E/AndroidRuntime(6073): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2/com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.CustomWebView}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.CustomWebView

Comment: seems the end problem was : getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS); being called before content?  i just commented it out and it works now..

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling it with a parameter, you're starting an activity and putting an extra String in the intent bundle, which you never pull out of the bundle to use.

You need something like this at the beginning of `CustomWebView`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String url = extras.getString("url");
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the difference between an Activity's constructor and its `onCreate()` method.

A constructor is called when you explicitly create a new object;

```
Activity customWebView = new CustomWebView(url);
```

This is probably not how you want to go about creating new Activities.  Instead you want to use the intent system (which is what you've started to do).

```
Intent webView = new Intent(getContext(), CustomWebView.class);
webView.putExtra("url", "http://google.com");
webView.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getContext().startActivity(webView);
```

Using the intent system will call an empty constructor, and then once the Activity has been created, will call the `onCreate()` method, which you should override.  From here, you have access to the Intent that you used to start the Activity, and you can get the URL that you are passing as an argument.

You probably want something that looks like this:

```
public class CustomWebView extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url = intent.getStringExtra("url");

        //Do stuff with your URL
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code above to reflect your answer and am getting this error: 03-27 10:59:17.830: E/AndroidRuntime(6870): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2/com.sapientnitro.lcinstore2.CustomWebView}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

03-27 10:59:17.830: E/AndroidRuntime(6870): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: The error is that "requestFeature() must be called before adding content".  You must call `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);` before you call `setContentView(webview);`

Answer (score 0):

`requestFeature()` should be called before `setContentView`:

...

```
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(webview);
```

...